# What is the good way of working when moving from on-premise to Azure PaaS model?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, virtual-machine, azure-data-factory

We plan to migrate to Azure cloud and would like to know what is the recommened way of working, especially when the teams are used to working with dedicated UAT/DEV servers.

We have about 10 UAT physical database servers, each used for a different purpose. Some servers are used for integration testing, few for user acceptance testing, for chain testing etc.

We plan to use services such as Azure Data Factory (SSIS IR), Azure SQL Managed Instance, Virtual machines for custom applications

Creating the same number of database servers on cloud would be too expensive. How can we best deal with such scenario and how it is handled within your teams? Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused about your question. The title says you are looking to move to PaaS, but then you mention you want to use IaaS VMs instead of PaaS App Services. So, are you after a PaaS or IaaS solution? Is there a particular reason why you are also looking at Azure SQL Managed Instance instead of Azure SQL DB? Please clarify a bit and then I can help provide additional details given the direction you are after.  But, there's no way to shortcut the number of databases you need.  If you need them, you need them.  So just create them. Azure SQL Elastic Pools are quite cost-effective.

Comment: The reason for Azure sql database managed instance is to lift and shift the existing database objects. This is still under discussion. We do have a lot of cross database queries and unlike Azure sql which doesn’t support cross db queries , with MI we can continue with existing queries without much rework . 
The other VM is for SSRS reports. We would later refactor those reports to Power BI.

Comment: @Ashan Actually, you want to migrate the Azure SQL MI(IaaS) to Azure SQL database(PaaS), but you haven't determined to do, am I right? You have a lot of worries about if the Azure SQL database can meet your request. That confused us that we don't know how to answer your question. There are many ways can achieve the Server/database migration. And you need to think about the cost according the Azure SQL database price tier and choose the best for you.

Comment: @Ashan what we can do is provide the ways/documents to help you migrate the database. It's hard to say which way is the good way, just up to you. The way you think simplest and effective is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

As the use case for the migration is lift and shift and since you have multiple cross database queries,SQL Managed instance would be the best fit.
As SQL MI is very costly, so having different MI instances for different environments would prove to be very expensive (that too having <10 databases in 1 instance)
Would suggest have 2 SQL MI Instances :
1 for lower environment like Dev, test,UAT and 1 for Prod environment.
Have database names as xyz_env and create variables within DACPAC and parameterize it avoid any manual code changes for each database deployments.

Though you can also leverage Azure SQL database and the concept of elastic queries(for cross database queries) which would be some additional efforts but worth leveraging complete benefits over PaaS as there wont be any Vnet and databases can be directly accessible via other Azure resources and also would be very cost effective.